# How to ignore all values in list that are not numbers

Tags: python, list

I need to get all values that are numbers from:

```
lst = [7, 18, 3, 'a', True, (2,3)]
```

So I need to get 7,8 and 3. How can I get that?

I tried using function `isnumeric` and `isdigit`.
It returns error ->

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

Comment: You tried doing something, please share the code you tried with, then we can help you figure out the problem.

Comment: `[x for x in lst if str(x).isnumeric()]`

Comment: How is it supposed to work for floats, e.g. `1.4`?

Comment: @CeliusStingher probably because question in not entirely clear and there's been a lot of similar questions answered already. I don't know what indentation has to do with anything.

Comment: @alex Exactly my thought. If OP would have spent just a few mins looking around on SO using the search function he/she could probably solve it quicker than asking this question. Also no code..

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `type()`

```
lst = [7, 18, 3, 'a', True, (2,3)]
new_lst = [i for i in lst if type(i) in [int, float]]
```

Comment: A float would be numeric and not considered in this example.

Comment: Fixed it to work with float, although the example user gave was only integers. Plus, `isdigit()` only accepts integers, so I assumed they only needed integers @CeliusStingher

Comment: Thanks, type(i) in [int,float] solved problem

Answer (score -1):

Use list comprehension

Here is a quick example

```
lst = [7, 18, 3, 'a', True, (2,3)]
[x for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]

==> [7, 18, 3, True]
```

"True" gets in the way here cause

```
int.__subclasses__()
[<type 'bool'>]
```

But this is another question...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP specifically gave the result they wanted and yours does not comply to that.

Comment: "I need to get all values that are numbers", by default in Python booleans are numbers... What do you want me to do ? Change the language standards?

Comment: *So I need to get 7,8 and 3.* Maybe you should check the other answer which clearly works as intended.